# Dynamically adding nodes to Phoenix cluster

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I recently read Chris McCords [article](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/01/28/running-elixir-and-phoenix-projects-on-a-cluster-of-nodes) about distributing Phoenix application on cluster.

I'm wondering is it possible to dynamically add nodes to existing cluster via `net_kernel:connect_node/1`. Could it work? In the tutoria Chris used config file though...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

It's too much to go into detail in a single answer, so here are some links that should help you:

- http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2010-September/053148.html
- https://github.com/erlware/resource_discovery
- [What's the best way to run a gen_server on all nodes in an Erlang cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531966/whats-the-best-way-to-run-a-gen-server-on-all-nodes-in-an-erlang-cluster)
- [How to add a node to an mnesia cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787755/how-to-add-a-node-to-an-mnesia-cluster)